# Why is the scheme required for AuthenticationHeaderValue?

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, authorization, dotnet-httpclient

I am setting the authorization header of an `HttpClient` in the following manner:

```
httpClient
    .DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(null, "abc");
```

...but am getting the exception:

> "scheme" of the AuthenticationHeaderValue cannot be null.

Why must the `AuthenticationHeaderValue` have a scheme? Is this required by a specific RFC?

Comment: Disappointing that the accepted answer is not really answering your question why you must use a scheme, or how you can do it without a scheme, because a scheme is not always required (e.g. custom authorization header check).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The scheme is used to determine what kind of authentication you are using:

- Basic
- Oauth
- Bearer
- Digest
- etc.

The header will look like this:

```
{
   "key": "Authorization",
   "value": "<scheme> <parameter>"
}
```

Try to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to see what is generated based on the different types of authentication supported by HTTP.

Comment: Is there a complete list of schemes available somewhere?

Comment: A quick googling found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/understanding-http-authentication

Comment: Really surprised that there isn't an enum containing these values. :O

Comment: Maybe because it is not a finite list? Just guessing :)

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes you cannot set the Authorization header with a scheme. This is also the case on a project where I am working on right now. I need to connect to the API from [TOPdesk](https://developers.topdesk.com/index.html), but there is no scheme specified.

The Authorization header from TOPdesk must have a value like `TOKEN id="0d1739df-8952-41c0-94cd-b25287446b22"` so I cannot use a scheme. I solved the problem by adding the Authorization header like the following example, and it works like a charm.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"TOKEN id=\"{token}\"");
```

Comment: In this case, surely the scheme is "TOKEN"?

Comment: @EdB precisely, in this case it is a custom scheme "TOKEN"

Comment: so `Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("TOKEN", "id=\"{token}\"")`?

Comment: @JamesBarrass indeed that does work in this example (except for missing the $ character before the string declaration of the value). For the specific use-case of the original question this would have not worked because only the value is expected.

Answer (score 3):

For me the Authorization Token I needed was only a base64 encoded string, no scheme.

Example: "Authorization: SnVzdCBhIGR1bW15IHRva2Vu".
The API Endpoint I was connecting to refused to accept a scheme like "Basic" or anything else.
I had to use:

```
HttpRequestMessage hrMessage = new HttpRequestMessage ();
hrMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "SnVzdCBhIGR1bW15IHRva2Vu");
```

That worked.

Comment: TryAddWithoutValidation was the key part I needed